# How to report and fix errors while iterating?

Tags: python, loops, iteration, typeerror, store

I would like to iterate through elements in raw_data below, and

- store the value of f(x)
- when f(x) gives an error, show the error msg and store this message
- fix the error that arised due to type, ie "four" instead of 4

Would it be possible to do all three at the same time?

```
import math
import sys

raw_data = [5,"four", -3,2,1]

def f(x):
    return math.log(x)
```

What I have so far is:

```
import math
import sys

raw_data = [5,"four", -3,2,1]

def f(x):
    return math.log(x)

for x in raw_data:
    try:
        print(f(x))
    except:
        print("error:",sys.exc_info()[0])
```

This gives me a list results:

```
1.6094379124341003
error: <class 'TypeError'>
error: <class 'ValueError'>
0.6931471805599453
0.0
```

How would I

a) store the values of f(x) where there are no errors

b) where there are errors, report and store the error message

c) correct the type error?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: How do you intend to fix the errors ??

Comment: for example, I would like to replace 'four' with the number 4. The other error I would just report an error

Comment: Will you replace "minus three hundred fifty five" by -355 ? And what about 27 when a string is expected ? In reality is there any fix that makes sense ?

Comment: in your scenario I would guess that we would replace the text by -355, then just report an error. The idea is just that I would want to convert all to numbers first so that the log function can read it

Comment: A last question: how do you plan to replace "minus three hundred fifty five" by -355 ?

Comment: I'd have to go in and correct it somehow - I'm not expecting an automatic correction! Basically, I just have a dataset where where the numbers sometimes come in string for some reason so im wondering how best to approach this

Comment: Have someone proofread the input !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to store the function results and error messages in two different lists, I'd suggest creating two lists and appending to one or the other in your `try/except`.  Use a dictionary to do the translation between specific strings and their numeric equivalents.

```
results = []
errors = []
num_names = {
    'four': 4,
}

for x in raw_data:
    x = num_names.get(x, x)
    try:
        results.append(f(x))
    except Exception as e:
        errors.append(repr(e))

print("Results:", *results, sep='\n')
print("Errors:", *errors, sep='\n')
```

```
Results:
1.6094379124341003
1.3862943611198906
0.6931471805599453
0.0
Errors:
ValueError('math domain error')
```